# How to add a helping app along with my main application

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I want helping app for proper working of my main application.My idea is to get Broadcast for `android.intent.action.PACKAGE_RESTARTED` and `android.intent.action.PACKAGE_DATA_CLEARED` but problem is Document states `that the` [**Restarted**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_RESTARTED)/[**Cleared**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_DATA_CLEARED) `package does not receive this broadcast` .So I want to make a helping app that will be called when my main app is restarted or cleaned.And from there I can tell my main app that package is restared/cleaned so perform according to that .

So Finally my question is how can I do that, should I ask user to install that app for better performance or is there any way to intall it without asking user.**Or anybody having better idea to tackle my problem without using helping app**.

Comment: i think you can capture package restart and data cleared event in same application.

Comment: @SanketKachhela no actully document says restarted package itself cant receive this broadcast..I have provided the link also

Answer (score 0):

Store a param into SharedPreferences. If the app was cleared, the param disapears and controling this you could decide if show (or not) the intro help

Comment: clearing memory does not clears SharedPreferences data..Thank for precious time

Answer (score 0):

First it's important to understand that what you are asking to do is **security volition** and could be used to **harm the user**.

Lets hope that my next advises will not be used under such context:

1. Helping app is indeed a good option. You cannot avoid asking the user to install it, and more important, review it's permissions. How ever you do not have to create a lunch activity there, so the user will not be able to run it. The helper application can create a service to listen for those broadcasts. Also it will be a good idea to make the service [foreground](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground%28int,%20android.app.Notification%29).
2. You can create an [alarm](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) that will wake up your service every second. If your activity been killed, you would notice this. You can use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html), to save your application state: `AppStarted`, `AppFinished`. Also it will protect you from Force-Stop.
3. Also I think if you only make a service that is running in background(foreground), other applications would not be able to kill you, only when the user will press on the force-stop button, from the applications settings.

Comment: Right it is security volition.But actually  the problem is that after I use the built in Task Manager to Clean Memory/Ram, My widget stops working.And android.intent.action.PACKAGE_DATA_CLEARED broadcast cannot be received by same package ,which is cleaned .AFAIK this is the only way to acknowledge that task manager cleaned my data.But my helping app can acknowledge it as it is different package .And from there I can reinitialize my widget onUpdate(problem solved).here is my orignal question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20630888/widget-does-not-works-after-clear-memory plz have a look